# C++ Function being called when it isn't supposed to

Tags: c++, function

I'm nearly finished working on a small guessing game, but i have run into a problem I don't know how to work around.

The problem is with the check_guess function that is checking to make sure the guess being input is a number between 1 and 100.

When running the program the first time, everything works fine.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/644yd.png (I would post images if my reputation weren't so low)

But every time after, where yes to play again is chosen, the program runs through the check_guess function and displays "Invalid Input" when it shouldn't

https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4rpb.png

I'm not sure why the program is behaving this way.

The code for the entire program is here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>      //for rand
#include <ctime>            //for time
#include <string>
#include <sstream>      //for conversions from string to int

using namespace std;

int check_guess(int tries) { //function for limiting the input of guess
    string guess = "";
    int result = 0;

    do {
        getline (cin, guess);

        istringstream convert(guess);
        if ( !(convert >> result) || (result < 1 || result > 100) ) {
            result = 0;
            cout << "Invalid Input.\n" << endl;
            cout << "You have " << tries << " tries: ";
        }
    } while (result == 0);

    return result;
}

bool play_again() { //function for limiting the input of mode
    bool quit;
    string yn;
    do {
        cin >> yn;
        if          ( yn == "y" || yn == "yes" ) {
                        quit = false;
        }
        else if ( yn == "n" || yn == "no" ) {
                        quit = true;
        }
        else { 
            yn = "invalid";
            cout << "Invalid input.\n\nEnter 'y' or 'n': ";
        }
    } while ( yn == "invalid" );
    return quit;
}

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));         //sets seed to be random
    int mystery = 0;        //defines mystery number
    int guess = 0;          //defines guess
    int tries = 5;          //defines trys
    bool quit = false;  //defines replay or quit

    cout << "----------------------------------\n";

    do  {                                               //while mode is not set to quit, keep     playing
        tries = 5;                                  //resets tries each new game
        mystery = rand() % 100 + 1; //sets mystery number to be random
        guess = 0;
        cout << "Pick a number between 1 and 100.\n\nYou have 5 tries: ";

        while (tries != 0) {                //loops until you have no tries left
            guess = check_guess(tries);

            if (guess == mystery) { tries = 0; }    //if you guess right it ends the loop
            else                                  { tries--; }      //guessing wrong lowers tries by 1

            if ( tries != 0 && guess > mystery) {
                cout << guess << " is too high.\n" << endl;
                cout << "You have " << tries << " tries: ";
            }
            if ( tries != 0 && guess < mystery) {
                cout << guess << " is too low.\n"  << endl; 
                cout << "You have " << tries << " tries: ";
            }   
        }


        if (guess == mystery) {     //if guess == mystery by time loop ends you win
            cout << "Got it! You Win!\n" << endl;
        }
        else {                                      //if not, you lose
            cout << "You Lose! The number was: " << mystery << ".\n" <<endl;
        }

        cout << "-------------------\n";
        cout << "Play Again?(y/n): ";   //ask user to play again
        quit = play_again();
        cout << "-------------------\n";
        if (quit == false)
            cout << endl;
    } while (quit == false);

    cout << "----------------------------------" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I'm not sure how to fix this.

Comment: You should probably do some simple debugging to see if the conditions to your ``if(!(convert >> result) || (result < 1 || result > 100)`` statement are what you expect them to be. That will guide you to the problem pretty quickly I expect.

Comment: isn't that the 'end of line' after the 'y' answer from the "Play Again?(y/n): " question? It leads to an empty line the first time you think you are reading a number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this line:

```
cin >> yn;
```

only reads the 'y' but not the end of line. As a result, the next execution of this instruction

```
getline (cin, guess);
```

initializes guess to an empty string.

Comment: Please suggest a solution.

Comment: either explicitly discard the end of line or use something like 'getline (cin, yn);'

Comment: There's also `cin.ignore()`.

Answer (score 0):

On line 19, import the code "cin.ignore();" without quotations.
So your code reads as

`int check_guess(int tries) { //function for limiting the input of guess
    string guess = "";
    int result = 0;

```
do {
    getline (cin, guess);

    istringstream convert(guess);
    if ( !(convert >> result) || (result < 1 || result > 100) ) {
        result = 0;
        cin.ignore();
        cout << "Invalid Input.\n" << endl;
        cout << "You have " << tries << " tries: ";
    }
} while (result == 0);

return result;
```

}
`

and so on. This stops input into the console briefly. You're code is reading the 'y' to try again as the input for the number when you restart as well. Putting in the little line cin.ignore(), stops it from inputting y twice.

Answer (score 0):

Change play_again() to:

```
bool play_again() { //function for limiting the input of mode
    bool quit;
    string yn;
    do {
        getline (cin, yn);
        if          ( yn == "y" || yn == "yes" ) {
                        quit = false;
        }
        else if ( yn == "n" || yn == "no" ) {
                        quit = true;
        }
        else { 
            yn = "invalid";
            cout << "Invalid input.\n\nEnter 'y' or 'n': ";
        }
    } while ( yn == "invalid" );
    return quit;
}
```